# How to replace NULL values in T-SQL PIVOT with dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace `NULL` values with `0` in the following query, however without luck. I know I need to create another column list for the `SELECT` statement, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

How do I do this properly?

My query:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @COLS AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @COLS = ISNULL(@COLS + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(ItemCategoryName)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           ItemCategoryName
    FROM sgdw.fact.RetailSales RS
         JOIN SGDW.dim.Item I ON RS.ItemID = I.ItemID
    WHERE RS.CalendarID >= '20190101'
          AND storeid = '92'
          AND DATALENGTH(ItemCategoryName) != 0
) AS Properties;
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT RetailSalesAmountIncludingVATDKK, 
           ItemCategoryName, 
           ReceiptCode
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM sgdw.fact.RetailSales
        WHERE storeid = ''92''
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *
        FROM sgdw.fact.RetailSales_hist
        WHERE CalendarID >= ''20190101''
              AND storeid = ''92''
    ) RS
    JOIN SGDW.dim.Item I ON RS.ItemID = I.ItemID
    JOIN SGDW.dim.Store S ON S.StoreID = RS.StoreID
) SourceTable

PIVOT (Sum(RetailSalesAmountIncludingVATDKK) FOR [ItemCategoryName] IN (' + @COLS + '))  as PivotTable';
EXEC sp_executesql 
     @SQL;
```

Comment: Debug Hint : Do a `print @SQL` and verify your query

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server (starting with 2008), Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehousen you can bye **COALESCE** method
like

```
 SELECT @COLS_SUM = @COLS_SUM + 'COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(finmonth) + ',0)+' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT finmonth FROM YOUR_TABLE ) AS tmp
SELECT @COLS_SUM = ','+ SUBSTRING(@COLS_SUM, 0, LEN(@COLS_SUM)) +' AS TOTAL'
```

for more info check https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1391827/Dealing-with-nulls-dynamic-columns-in-pivot

Answer (score 0):

Append This

```
SELECT @COLS = 'ISNULL('+REPLACE(@COLS,',',',0 ) , ISNULL(') + ',0 )'
```

After this block

```
SELECT @COLS = ISNULL(@COLS + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(ItemCategoryName)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           ItemCategoryName
    FROM sgdw.fact.RetailSales RS
         JOIN SGDW.dim.Item I ON RS.ItemID = I.ItemID
    WHERE RS.CalendarID >= '20190101'
          AND storeid = '92'
          AND DATALENGTH(ItemCategoryName) != 0
) AS Properties;
```

Comment: By appending, do you simply mean adding the line before the block? If so, that didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: I intended to say to handle your columns by dynamically appending `Isnull(<YourColumns>,0)` at the time of columns construction into one variable (lets say @Cols )

Comment: I see. But now I'm just getting `Commands completed successfully` with no result.